# Is it wrong to use "How much passed" without time?

Tags: time

Is it correct to say "I noticed how much passed since we connected." Would one deduce time by reading this? Or you have to specify "time" after much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the word *time*. In the sentence

> Much time passed.

the word *much* is acting as an adjective, telling us the quantity of time.

Now, *much* can also be used as a noun, with various meanings, all rather abstract. Usually, as in the sentence

> Much passed.

the word *much* means "a great deal" or "a great quantity" in some generic sense. A good synonym would be "many things". But this usage of *much* has nothing to do with time.